# Ember App Kit Tests with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-app-kit

I'm importing ember-data into the public/index.html file, and my application works well. I did notice JSLint complaining that

```
 'DS' is not defined.
```

This morning I tried to write some tests, and noticed the testrunner also complaining that

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: DS is not defined
```

How to I get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need a

```
"predef": [
    "DS",
    ...
]
```

in your `.jshintrc`?

Answer (score 0):

It might be a loading order issue.  I think you want to make sure that you include jQuery first, then Ember, then Ember Data, and then finally your App code.  Alternatively, it could be that something in index.html is a little screwy and is preventing the `script` tag for Ember Data from rendering correctly.  Any chance you can post a JSBin?

Comment: To clarify, the code works beautifully, its just JSLint (and the tester) that are upset. The actual app has no problem executing